# Peticiones Ajax al mismo Servlet

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, servlets

Estoy comenzando a programar aplicaciones Web que realizan peticiones **Ajax** al servidor empleando **jQuery**.

Cuando realizo una petición **Ajax**, implemento un `servlet` que va a procesar esa petición (en el método `doPost` o `doGet`).

#### Mi duda es la siguiente:

¿Cada petición tiene que ir dirigido a un `servlet` diferente?

Y si no es así, ¿cómo diferencio en la URL de la petición el método del `servlet` que va a procesar una u otra petición?

He pensado en enviar un parámetro para distinguir las peticiones **Ajax**, pero no sé si es lo correcto.

Answer (score 1):

estás en lo cierto, se puede utiliza el mismo servlet con un parámetro (o varios) que te distinga entre las diferentes llamadas.
Por ejemplo:

tienes la siguiente url : http://localhost:8080/miServlet?opc=opc1 luego en el servlet lo recoges en el método doGet con String opc = request.getParameter("opc") y distingue entre las posibles opciones con un if(opc.equals("opc1")), la segunda opción sería algo así http://localhost:8080/miServlet?opc=opc2 y bastaría que en el doGet añadieras un else if(opc.equals("ocp2"))

Un saludo.